# Reset my click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following click function. I'm looking for a way so that when it is compleated, it will reset, and is ready to run again. How should i do that?

```
$('body').on('click', '#ConfirmBet', function () {
    function randomImg() {
        var imgs = $('.CoinImages');
        var randomOne = Math.floor(imgs.length * Math.random());
        $('#winner').fadeIn().attr('src', $(imgs[randomOne]).attr('src'));
        $('#winner').addClass("WinImage");
        if ($('#winner').attr('src') === $('.selected').attr('src')) {
            alert('You Win!');
        } else {
            alert('You Lose!');
        }
    }
    var counter = 5;
    var c = setInterval(function () {
        if (counter > 0) {
            counter--;
            $('#counter').html(counter);
            $("#BetInput").val("");
            $("#BetInput").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#tCoin").removeClass("selected");
            $("#ctCoin").removeClass("selected");
            $(".CustomTextT").html("");
            $(".CustomTextCT").html("");
            $("#winner").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            clearInterval(c);
            randomImg();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMeErb)

This codepen show's what my script does, but as you see, it keeps saying lose. no matter what image you hit.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset and ready to run again"?  Any time this click event is raised, this function will execute again.

Comment: @AdiLevin So it can run again. Currently, it just displays the same resoult everytime. So i needs to reset, when it has been run. Just like if you refresh the website :)

Comment: @David Right now, it displays the same alert, every time after the 5 sec countdown.

Comment: Have added a codepen so that you can see what it does, and that it keeps selecting the same result as the first!

Answer (score 0):

In your `setInterval` handler function, you are removing the `selected` class in the `counter > 0` case. Then in `randomImg` you are looking for an element with the `selected` class to determine which image was selected. Since you already removed the class, the check always fails.

I think you want to redo your `setInterval` handler logic like this:

```
    if (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        $('#counter').html(counter);
    } else {
        clearInterval(c);
        randomImg();
        $("#BetInput").val("");
        $("#BetInput").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#tCoin").removeClass("selected");
        $("#ctCoin").removeClass("selected");
        $(".CustomTextT").html("");
        $(".CustomTextCT").html("");
        $("#winner").removeClass("hidden");
    }
```